# How to close expanded mobile top bar in Foundation via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, menu, zurb-foundation, menubar

I'm wondering if there is someway to close the expanded topbar in Foundation on click on one of the items? I guess I'm looking for something to put in the center of this:

```
$('#some-menu-item').click(function() {
    //some function to collapse the menu
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out by lifting lines 174-176 of Foundation's [topbar.js](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js).

```
$('#some-menu-item').click(function() {
    $('.top-bar, [data-topbar]').css('height', '').removeClass('expanded');
});
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks JPollock. Saved me masses of time!

Comment: Awesome, this saved me a ton of time. I do wish the #foundation team fixed this issue or at least made it optional.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way:

```
$(document).on("click", ".top-bar li", function () {
     Foundation.libs.topbar.toggle($('.top-bar'));
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is my quick solution for the same problem:

Put this on header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 /*Fix toggle menu*/
 function fixToggleMenu()
 {
    Foundation.libs.topbar.toggle($('.top-bar'));
 }
</script>
```

Then, call this function in your href:

```
...
<li><a href="#services" onClick="fixToggleMenu();">Services</a></li>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

A much cleaner way (*I think*)

```
$('#some-menu-item').click(function() {
    $('nav.top-bar').foundation('topbar', 'toggle');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#some-menu-item").click(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:10},200).attr('id', 'topbar');
  });
```

This should do the trick replace the height value for the size you would like the top bar to close to.

Comment: This just shrank the menu item itself.